# WebRTC Datachannel for high bandwidth application

Tags: webrtc, rtcdatachannel, webrtc-android

I want to send unidirectional streaming data over a WebRTC datachannel, and is looking of the best configuration options (high BW, low latency/jitter) and others' experience with expected bitrates in this kind of application.

My test program sends chunks of 2k, with a bufferedAmountLowThreshold event callback of 2k and calls send again until bufferedAmount exceeds 16k. Using this in Chrome, I achieve ~135Mbit/s on LAN and ~20Mbit/s from/to a remote connection, that has 100Mbit/s WAN connection on both ends.

What is the limiting factor here?

How can I see if the data is truly going peer to peer directly, or whether a TURN server is used?

My ultimate application will use the google-webrtc library on Android - I'm only using JS for prototyping. Can I set options to speed up bitrate in the library, that I cannot do in official JS APIs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many variables that impact throughput and it also highly depends on how you've measured it. But I'll list a couple of things I have adjusted to increase the throughput of WebRTC data channels.

Disclaimer: I have not done these adjustments for libwebrtc but for my own WebRTC data channel library called [RAWRTC](https://github.com/rawrtc/rawrtc), which btw also compiles for Android. However, both use the same SCTP library underneath, both use some OpenSSL-ish library and UDP sockets, so all of this should be appliable to libwebrtc.

Note that WebRTC data channel implementations using [usrsctp](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/) are usually CPU bound when executed on the same machine, so keep that in mind when testing. With RAWRTC's default settings, I'm able to achieve ~520 Mbit/s on my i7 5820k. From my own tests, both Chrom(e|ium) and Firefox were able to achieve ~350 Mbit/s with default settings.

Alright, so let's dive into adjustments...

#### UDP Send/Receive Buffer Size

The default send/receive buffer of UDP sockets in Linux is quite small by default. If you can, you may want to adjust it.

#### DTLS Cipher Suites

Most Android devices have ARM processors without hardware AES support. ChaCha20 usually performs better in software and thus you may want to prefer it.

(This is what RAWRTC negotiates by default, so I have not included it in the end results.)

#### SCTP Send/Receive Buffer Size

The default send/receive window size of usrsctp, the SCTP stack used by libwebrtc, [is 256 KiB](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/Manual.md#usrsctp_sysctl_set_sctp_sendspace) which is way too small to achieve high throughput with moderate delay. The theoretical maximum throughput is limited by `mbits = (window / (rtt_ms / 1000)) / 131072`. So, with the default window of `window=262144` and a fairly moderate RTT of `rtt_ms=20`, you will end up with a theoretical maximum of 100 Mbit/s.

The practical maximum is below that... actually, way lower than the theoretical maximum (see [my test results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ze2hZl9KZJ1hKcm5Y9J0OIknQCBHUpw5eefskCc8xpM)). This may be a bug in the usrsctp stack (see [sctplab/usrsctp#245](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/issues/245)).

The buffer size has been increased in Firefox (see [bug 1051685](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051685)) but not in libwebrtc used by Chrom(e|ium).

#### Release Builds

Optimisation level 3 makes a difference (duh!).

#### Message Size

You probably want to send 256 KiB sized messages.

Unless you need to support Chrome < ??? (sorry, I currently don't know where it landed...), then the maximum message size is 64 KiB (see [issue 7774](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7774)).

Unless you also need to support Firefox < 56, in which case the maximum message size is 16 KiB (see [bug 979417](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=979417)).

It also depends on how much you send before you pause sending (i.e. the buffer's *high water mark*), and when you continue sending after the buffer has been drained (i.e. the buffer's *low water mark*). My tests have shown that targeting a *high water mark* of 1 MiB and setting a *low water mark* of 256 KiB results in adequate throughput.

This reduces the amount of API calls and *can* increase throughput.

#### End Results

Using optimisation level 3 with default settings on RAWRTC brought me up to ~600 Mbit/s.

Based on that, increasing the SCTP and UDP buffer sizes to 4 MiB brought me up further to ~700 Mbit/s, with one CPU core at 100% load.

However, I believe there is still room for improvements but it's unlikely to be low-hanging.

---

> How can I see if the data is truly going peer to peer directly, or whether a TURN server is used?

Open `about:webrtc` in Firefox or `chrome://webrtc-internals` in Chrom(e|ium) and look for the chosen ICE candidate pair. Or use Wireshark.

Comment: Hi Lennart,
Thanks for your elaborate answer. Using RAWRTC seems like an even better choice for us.

Compatibility with browsers is not a necessity for us - what is the best options for us wrt. APIs and channel options?

I'm only familiar with WebRTC API and ORTC seems to be split into mulitple tools. What is the complte connection process using ORTC?

Comment: ORTC is just a different and lower level API, and if you don't need WebRTC support, then I would use ORTC instead. The data channel API however is absolutely identical. For the connection process, take a look at [one of the example tools](https://github.com/rawrtc/rawrtc/blob/master/tools/data-channel-sctp-echo.c) in the RAWRTC code base. Basically, you exchange parameters and call *start* on each transport.

Comment: Technically, if a peer opens multiple data channels against different peers, wouldn't the peer be able to achieve higher throughput? (assuming that `usrsctp` throughput limit is applicable **per** data channel, and not for the whole system).