# Do browser engines limit WebRTC speeds?

Tags: webrtc, p2p, peerjs

I am using PeerJS, which is a JavaScript implementation of WebRTC.
I am using it for sending data through the DataChannel.

Are there any speed restrictions by the browser engines?

I am not able to send more than ~20MB/s even though both instances of my application are running on the same machine.
The data is not being sent over the network as can be seen using the system monitor of my Linux machine.
I have tried both Chrome and Firefox.

Has anyone experienced faster speeds using the WebRTC data channel?
I presumed that a peer-to-peer connection should be the fastest means of data transportation and am wondering if that's my implementation or a protocol issue.
I am aware that window size plays a major role in performance especially.
Any practical experiences with PeerJS that could be helpful?

Comment: I've just bumped into the problem too. Noticed that WebTorrent, ShareDrop, and others were all limited to about 30 MB/s, even when transferring between different browser tabs on same device. I created a bare-bones demo with no packet ordering, and no re-transmission of lost data, and it still won't go over 30 MB/s: https://github.com/szimek/sharedrop/issues/154#issuecomment-1555905938 Very surprising considering that I can download from a remote server in a different country at 100 MB/s on my internet connection. CRBug issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1447329

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [WebRTC Datachannel for high bandwidth application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327783/webrtc-datachannel-for-high-bandwidth-application) gives advices on how to reach higher throughput in WebRTC data channels.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I've already read it but found it does not really answer my question.
Specifically, it does not in terms of using PeerJS.

Answer (score 0):

if you want Download Speed, Create N*PeerConnection send the file might be helpful.

what you are try to do is the same as Single Thread Download File (TCP/IP), Nothing Different Except the Transport Protocol.

You can try the Speed Test Under Single Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am aware that the weaktest link is the up/download speed of either network using a 2*P2P connection. I don't expect more than that.

I am however running both clients on one device which would make the maximum speed theoretically dependant on CPU and RAM speed. 20MB/s is not even near that speed by factors.
I have also tried two different devices in the same Gigabit network: Even slower.

Comment: @dmuensterer if you just need improve the program, adjust the UDP buffer size may be helpful, there're many factors. i just checked the source code of google webrtc, not found any soft limit on datachannel.

Comment: @dmuensterer maybe you can try something like split the File into chunks, send it over N*Peer without modify others.

Comment: CPU: Disable encryption might be helpful (cpu intensive Job if there's no hardware Acceleration)  --disable-webrtc-encryption